# Spring and JPA 2.0 - Composite key in many to many relationship with extra column

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, many-to-many

I have two entities Foo and Bar in many-to-many relationship. The joining entity is `FooBar`, and since this entity has another property (its own id), I used `@ManyToOne` on the owner side (`FooBar`) and `@OneToMany` in dependent entities (`Foo` and `Bar`). How to create a `FooBarRepository` extending `CrudRepository` without the explicit composite key field inside `FooBar`? Ideally, I don't want to change the members of my `FooBar` class.

I tried to use `@IdClass`, but I don't want to have fields `fooId` and `barId` inside `FooBar` and I am getting this exception:

`Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Property of @IdClass not found in entity com.nano.testers.test.FooBar: barId`

I also tried to follow the documentation of `IdClass` and reference columns by name explicitly, but I failed (maybe the solution lies somewhere here?)

> The names of the fields or properties in the primary key class and the primary key fields or properties of the entity must correspond and their types must be the same.

I tried to change the names of fields inside `Foo` and `Bar` to just `id`, so that they would be referenced as `foo_id` and `bar_id` in the joining table, but the exception was the same.

I don't want to use `@EmbeddedId`, if that means I need to have a field of `FooBarPk` type inside the `FooBar` class.

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id
    private Long fooId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<FooBar> foobars;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Bar {
    @Id
    private Long barId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bar", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<FooBar> foobars;
}
```

```
@Entity
//@IdClass(FooBarPk.class)
public class FooBar implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long fooBarId;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Foo foo;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Bar bar;

}
```

```
public class FooBarPk implements Serializable {
    private Long fooId;
    private Long barId;
    private Long fooBarId;
}
```

```
public interface FooBarRepository extends CrudRepository<FooBar, FooBarPk> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the names of the fields in the composite key class have to be the same as names of the referenced entities. I think these names don't follow the clean code principles, but I will have to live with this solution for now.

```
public class FooBarPk implements Serializable {
    private Long foo;
    private Long bar;
    private Long fooBarId;
}
```